# Duplicate rectangle and angular checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

When `<mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>` is called, it shows two rectangles, also happens the same with radioButton (just like the image below). Thanks.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtvD5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using material and materialize in the project. [angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD2IV.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).